# $f: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$. Then for all $n$ there exists $0=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=1$ s.t. $f(x_k)=\frac kn$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity

Let $f: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$. Then for all natural $n$ there exist $0=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=1$ such that $f(x_k)=\frac kn$.

I tried using the intermidiate value theorem. However, I cannot guarantee the order of the $x_k$ that is required in the question. How can I possibly continue?

Comment: Proceed by induction: first constructing $x_1$, then constructing $x_{k+1}$ given that $x_k$ has been constructed.

Comment: Given an $n$, I only have a finite number of elements to choose from. How can I use induction then?

Comment: Use finite induction

Comment: (a.k.a. [Limited mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Limited_mathematical_induction) on Wikipédia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an arbitrary positive integer $n$, since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, by Intermediate Value theorem, there exists some point $x_1\in [0,1]$, such that $$f(x_1)=\frac1n$$

Next, since $f$ is continuous on $[x_1,1]$, and $\frac2n\in[\frac1n,1]$ by Intermediate Value theorem, there exists some point $x_2\in [x_1,1]$, such that $$f(x_2)=\frac2n$$

keep going, and we can construct a sequence $0=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=1$ s.t. $f(x_k)=\frac kn$.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the intermediate value theorem (IVT) here if we are careful. We first find $x_1$ using the IVT, and this will have $x_0<x_1< x_n$. Now, we consider our function $f$ on the interval $[x_1, x_n]$. Here, we have $f(x_1) = 1/n$ and $f(x_n) = 1$ so by the IVT, we can find $x_1 < x_2 < x_n$ such that $f(x_2) = 2/n$. If we then repeat this process, we will get out $0=x_0< x_1 < \cdots < x_n = 1$ with $f(x_k) = k/n$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

For $0\le j\le n$ let $x_j=\min f^{-1}\{j/n\}.$

Each $x_j$ exists because each $f^{-1}\{j/n\}$ is a non-empty closed subset of $[0,1].$

If $j<j'$ we cannot have $x_j>x_{j'}.$ Otherwise there would exist $y\in [0,x_{j'}]\cap f^{-1}\{j/n\}$ (... because $j/n\in [0,j'/n]\subseteq  \{f(x): x\in [0,x_{j'}]\}$...). But then $y\in f^{-1}\{j/n\}\land y<x_{j'}<x_j=\min f^{-1}\{j/n\},$ which is absurd.

Therefore $j<j'\implies x_j<x_{j'}.$

x_{j'}